# Between the URL being entered and parsed by Rails the final slash is being replaced with a comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, shopify

I'm working on a Rails application that works with data via the Shopify API, however it has just started giving me 500 errors when certain resources are requested via a proxy (as set in the app settings in Shopify).

The request is along the lines of:

```
/app/my-application/customers/1234.json
```

however the error log on Heroku is showing a GET request to:

```
/app/my-application/cusotmers,1234.json
```

I'm using the [Shopify/shopify_api](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) gem which was recently updated, otherwise nothing else in the config/routes has changed since this error began occurring.

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated!

*I'll happily provide more information if anything relevant is missing above.*

Comment: You are on the right way, can you post the part of your routes file that concern this resource, and also the line of your code that call the related _path method please

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire turns out to be a Shopify issue (see accepted answer), thanks for the response though.

Comment: Sure, glad you found an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in Shopify's service to proxy requests to applications.

I have just deployed a fix for the issue.  I take full responsibility for the issue, and will try to improve our tests to avoid similar issues in the future.

Comment: thanks that's all working now. Greatly appreciate the quick response.